# How can I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

> I want to sort this dictionary by points if points  equals sort by goal difference, if then equals sort  by country name

```
spain_team = {'name': 'Spain', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 0, 'draws': 2, 'goal difference': 2, 'Goals For': 7, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 5}
portogal_team = {'name': 'Portogal', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'Goals For': 5, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 4}
iran_team = {'name': 'Iran', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'Goals For': 5, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 4}
moraco_team = {'name': 'Moraco', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -2, 'Goals For': 4, 'Goals Against': 6, 'points': 3}
x = [iran_team,spain_team,portogal_team,moraco_team]
for i in x:print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by providing the `key` argument to the `sorted` function. You can either provide it as a lambda or use `itemgetter` like below:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from pprint import pprint

spain_team = {'name': 'Spain', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 0, 'draws': 2, 'goal difference': 2, 'Goals For': 7, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 5}
portogal_team = {'name': 'Portogal', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'Goals For': 5, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 4}
iran_team = {'name': 'Iran', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 1, 'draws': 1, 'goal difference': 0, 'Goals For': 5, 'Goals Against': 5, 'points': 4}
moraco_team = {'name': 'Moraco', 'wins': 1, 'loses': 2, 'draws': 0, 'goal difference': -2, 'Goals For': 4, 'Goals Against': 6, 'points': 3}

x = [iran_team, spain_team, portogal_team, moraco_team]

sorted_list = sorted(x, key=itemgetter('points', 'goal difference', 'name'))

pprint(sorted_list)
```

If you need the list sorted in reverse order, set the `reverse` argument:

```
sorted_in_reverse = sorted(x, key=itemgetter('points', 'goal difference', 'name'), reverse=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer , 
But not yet sorted by name, 
Iran and Portugal each have four points and are equal and at the same time the goal difference is equal, so they should be sorted like this
Because the letter(i) is ahead of the letter(p)
need first Spain and Iran second Portugal third Morocco fourth

Comment: You want reverse (descending) order for points and goal difference, but forward (alphabetic) order for name, so itemgetter won't really work for this -- pretty much requires a custom sort order using a lambda.